# How can I extract names and handwritten numbers from images (or pdf files) in python?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, ocr, python-tesseract

I want to build a project in which, when I put a pdf file it **extracts** from it **printed names** and **handwritten numbers** then **put them in a CSV file ( excel file )**
Please note that the pdf files has a **table** in which we find **names in a column** and **handwritten marks in the other column**
So can you suggest an example or best **python frameworks or engines** ou there?
**Please** make sure to see an **example** in this image below
[image: example of the image or pdf file]
**THANK YOU IN ADVANCE**

Comment: For handwritten you have to train a model to detect handwritten digits,and for scanned document part  you can use tessaract. i would suggest to use Keras

Comment: did you try google image APIs? If you can use non local code...

Answer (score 0):

The Python-Framework 'Tesseract' can do what you are looking for. You may want to have a look at this blog. There are basic instructions described. [Tessereact for Python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/)

Comment: the problem is : tessract or pytessract can detect only the text thats is written in a specif language like full paragraph in eng or fr ... not names !  
names are a different type , i need to know how i can detect names

Comment: @Adem Youssef another way could be to build and train your own CNN. I would suggest using Keras with Tensorflow. For Numbers, you can use an MNIST-trained Network. There are similar solutions for letter-Detection..you may have to read your way through this topic

Comment: @Adem Youssef OpenCV provides useful functionalities to find and detect edges and stuff...maybe helpful too

Comment: thank you @sxeros for your help it kinda put me on the right way

Comment: @Adem Youssef glad to help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pytesseract for texts.
Pytesseract is an optical character recognition (OCR) tool for Python. It will help you in recognizing the text from the images.

For handwritten digits, you could go through Tensorflow or Keras with mnist dataset.